# Initialize OneSignal SDK on Ionic with React.js

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, onesignal, ionic-native, ionic-react

I'm trying to start with OneSignal SDK on a Ionic with React app, but I can't find any guide for React, all I find is for angular and I'm not pratice of typescript.

Where do I need to initialize OneSignal SDK?

I'm trying to do it in the App.componentDidMount such as:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.oneSignal.startInit(
        "XXXXXX-XXX-XXX-X-XXXXX",
        "YYYYYYYYYY"
    );

    this.props.oneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(
        this.props.oneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.InAppAlert
    );

    this.props.oneSignal.handleNotificationReceived().subscribe(() => {
        // do something when notification is received
    });

    this.props.oneSignal.handleNotificationOpened().subscribe(() => {
        // do something when a notification is opened
    });

    this.props.oneSignal.endInit();
}
```

but the IDE continues giving me errors about `this.oneSignal` does not exists in the type xxx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fault. 
I was importing this way:

```
import { OneSignal } from '@ionic-native/onesignal/ngx';
```

This the correct way for React.js:

```
import { OneSignal } from '@ionic-native/onesignal';
```

Comment: How would this be used inside of a functional component constructor rather than the class structure? I'm not having much luck have an instance of OneSignal to work with.

Comment: @Nick just creating an instance let oneSignal = OneSignal.startInit(api_key, app_id); then all operations can be done on the instance such as oneSignal.addSubscriptionObserver() etc